# mod_rewrite infinite loop problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to do the following with mod_rewrite

1. on the server there is a file about.htm (which is found in the root directory of the domain)
2. I need to redirect about.htm to about/
3. On the server still keep about.htm, hence when about/ is called, it actually loads up about.htm

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^about/$       about.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^about\.htm$   about/    [R=302]
```

I also tried changing it a bit and see what happends, but I always end up with an infinite loop of redirection or a 500 server error.

Any idea why it's not working as intended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the path in the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteRule ^about/$       about.htm [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /about\.htm
RewriteRule ^about\.htm$   about/    [R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this line should do the work.

```
RewriteRule ^about\.htm$   http://yourdomain.com/about/    [R=302]
```

Comment: doesn't /about/ need to be actually present on the server with this then? or not?

Comment: well, as long as you said 

>> I need to redirect about.htm to about/

presumably about/ exists on server.
However, about.htm may not even exist.